# How can I know if a Facebook account is personal account or a Company Type account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-accounts

Is there a graph API call to know if a given account is Business accounts or personal account?

When I call the graph API like this,

http://graph.facebook.com/11234545656556 (the number is fake for now)

I do not get any data point that tells me that this is a business account and therefore has no name/username etc..

I only get this response type

```
    {"id": "11234545656556",   
     "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=11234545656556",   
      "email": "myemail@mail.com,   
     "timezone": 0,   
     "locale": "en_US",   
     "verified": true,   
     "updated_time": "2012-05-31T22:32:52+0000",   
     "type": "user"}
```

Is there an API call to know the type of the account?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitively get this information via FQL:

```
SELECT type FROM profile WHERE id=11234545656556
```

There is an undocumented `/profile` endpoint in the Graph API, but it does not return a type.

The only other way to test for this would be to look for the presence of a certain field in the Graph API response. e.g. if the response contains `first_name`, then you know it is a user and if it contains `category`, then you know it is a page.

Comment: FQL response is always "user". I was wondering if there is a way to know this other than cheeking for the presence of a random field.

Comment: Then all your IDs are user IDs. Try this query: `SELECT id, name, type FROM profile WHERE id IN (40796308305,56381779049,19292868552,4,100004284151725,195466193802264)`

Comment: This is particular user account that has not visible wall, no personal data (basically is email/password) to access and manage one or more Facebook pages. I want to know if there is a way to tell the difference from the normal personal user accounts.

Comment: No. Officially, there is only one class of user account. That does not stop people from registering a user account in violation of the TOS.

Comment: When going to https://www.facebook.com/business/overview to create a page, after selecting Page name and category you are prompted to Create a Facebook Account with email and password (no name required, non personal account). This is a non personal account. TOS only says that "You will not create more than one personal account"

Comment: It sure looks like this is a personal account. It just appears to be an account geared towards the type-a personalities who can't be bothered to set their voice mail message -- let alone deal with Facebook. On that same screen, there is that "I already have a Facebook account" link at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. So far the only way to know if its a personal Facebook account is by checking if the response contains a  **name** attribute.

Following FQL (change the id to some known account):

```
  SELECT type, name, username, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id=11234545656556
```

Will return type `"user"` for personal or Business accounts.

Assuming **"11234545656556"** is a business account, name and username will return inconsistent results it might return blanks or `"name": "Facebook User"`.

Same FQL call for a personal account like this:

```
 SELECT type, name, username, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id=4
```

Will result in public personal info for that given user.

```
 {
 "data": [
   {
      "type": "user", 
      "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", 
      "username": "zuck", 
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck", 
      "pic": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/157340_4_3955636_s.jpg"
    }
  ]
```

}

Comment: When id not from a personal account FQL returns `"name": "Facebook User"` if you use a different account to query for that info. When doing FQL from queried account you get empty value for name.